# The git switch keeps the ignored folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `master` and `test` branch. In a `test` branch i have a `raw` folder that is listed in the `.gitignore` file. When I switch between `master` and `test` branches, I can see all the differences in the files as normal. The problem is that the `raw` folder is kept when I switch from `test` to `master`. This folder is ment to be the `test`-branch's folder and I want it to be removed from the directory when I switch to `master` branch. How can I make it?

Answer (score 3):

You’ve explicitly told Git to ignore the folder, so Git operations won’t affect the folder.

If you want Git to manage the folder, remove the entry from .gitignore and commit the folder on a branch.

Answer (score 2):

> This folder [named `raw`] is meant to be the `test`-branch's folder and I want it to be removed from the directory when I switch to `master` branch. How can I make [Git do that]?

You can't.  More precisely, you can't do that *and* make it *ignored*.  You can, however, get close: maybe close enough for your purposes.  You can simply make the files *not ignored*.

The reason for this is simple enough, but requires a bit of explanation and attention to detail.  (If you want, you can skip straight to the **Conclusion** section below.)

#### Git is about commits

You're thinking about Git as if it stored *files* kept in *folders*.  This simply is not the case.  What Git stores is not *files* but rather *commits*.

Now, each commit is made up *of* files, so you might think *what's the difference?*  The difference is pretty big:

- The files in a commit are not in folders.  They just have *names that have slashes in them*, such as `path/to/file.ext`.
- You can't work with *part of a commit*.<sup>1</sup>  You always have a whole commit, or else you don't have the commit at all.
- The files that are inside a commit are strictly read-only.  In fact, everything about *every* commit is read-only: no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.  (Not by you, and not even by Git itself.)

That last part is perhaps the most critical.  The files inside a commit are kept in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  The de-duplication is important because *every commit contains a full snapshot of every file*.  Most commits mostly re-use the same files as some previous commit, and by de-duplicating the read-only, Git-only files, Git avoids having its internal storage requirements grow too huge.

But, because nothing but Git itself can *read* those files, and literally *nothing* can *write* them, you can't actually get any work done with the files inside a commit as they appear in that commit.  What this means is that Git must *extract* all the files from some commit, before you can work with that commit.

When you go to make a *new* commit, Git takes *all the files you have told it about*—the full snapshot—and uses those to make the new commit.  The files in the new commit are then read-only: they are now saved forever, or at least, as long as that new commit keeps existing.

This is what `git checkout` or `git switch` is really about, then: it *extracts* a commit so that you can work on it.  The files that you can then see and read and write and otherwise use **are not in Git**.  They are in a work area that is yours to play with as you like.  Git calls this work area your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  (As of Git 2.5, you are not limited to just one working tree.  You can create more of them with `git worktree add`, although this answer won't go into any detail about that.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not strictly true: there are some ways to use Git (not the normal everyday ways) that would let you work with part of a commit.  This won't help solve your problem, though.

---

#### Branch names only exist to let you find commits

Your branch names `test` and `master` have only one thing to do with storing files.  Remember that, as noted above, Git's storage consists of *commits* (which then contain files that can be extracted for you to use).  Each commit is found by its *hash ID*.  These hash IDs are the big ugly numbers that `git log` prints before showing each commit.  The hash IDs look random (though they aren't actually random), and are unpredictable, and unsuitable for humans.  About the only way to get them right is to use the mouse to cut-and-paste them, or similar.  So *humans* don't normally use these hash IDs (except via cut-and-paste as needed).  Instead, Git gives us *branch names*.

What a branch name really does is store *one single commit hash ID*.  This commit is, by definition, the *last* commit of that branch.  We say that the branch name *points to* the commit.  Because holding the raw hash ID of some commit allows Git to *find* the commit, the branch name lets us find this last commit, which Git calls the *tip* commit of the branch.

(Side question: is the branch just a *name?*  Is it just the *last commit?*  Is it something else entirely?  The answer to these questions is "yes", or perhaps "no".  The problem here is that the word *branch* means something different every time we say it.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

Now, the secret trick here is that each *commit* **also** points to some earlier commit(s).  A commit isn't *just* a snapshot of every file.  That's the main data of a commit, to be sure; but a commit also contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it, and when, for instance.  One piece of metadata that Git sets up for itself is the hash ID of the *previous* commit.

This forms commits into backwards-looking chains.  From the *last* commit, we can find the *second-to-last* commit.  From that commit, we can find the third-to-last, and from there we can step back again to the fourth-to-last, and so on.  If we draw commits using single uppercase letters to stand in for the big ugly hash IDs, we get a picture that looks like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch-name
```

The *name*, in this case `branch-name`, holds the hash ID of the *last* commit, which is how we—or at least Git—will find commit `H`.  Commit `H` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which is how Git will find commit `G`.  Commit `G` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, and so on.

What this all means is that each branch *name* identifies *one particular commit*, but that's good enough to find *every previous commit*.  But "previous" doesn't exactly mean *earlier in time*.  We call this earlier or previous commit the *parent* of the commit.  Most commits have just one parent, as shown here.

#### Making multiple branches

Suppose we have a chain of backwards-pointing commits—and I'm going to get lazy about drawing the arrows between then here—that looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

The `HEAD` in parentheses here indicates that the branch we have checked out (or `git switch`-ed to) is `br1`.  That means our *current branch* is `br1`, and our *current commit* is the commit whose hash is `H` (well, whatever hash ID `H` really stands in for).

Let's now make a new *name*, `br2`, that *also points to commit `H`*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2
```

Note that at this point, all the commits we are showing here are on *both branches*.

Now let's make a couple of new commits, while still on branch `br1`:

```
             I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- br2
```

Our act of making a *new* commit told Git to:

- package up a new snapshot;
- add our name and email address as the person who made this new commit;
- gather a log message from us;
- use the current date-and-time as "when the commit is made";
- use commit `H`, the *current* commit at that time, as the *parent*, so that `I` points back to `H`;

and then—**this is the key to how branch names work**—Git writes `I`'s hash ID, whatever it is, into the *current branch name*, so that the name `br1` now finds commit `I`.

New commit `I` is only on branch `br1`.  It is the *last* commit on that branch.  But commit `H` is the *last* commit on branch `br2`.  Being the last commit on some branch doesn't mean there cannot be any *later* commits.  It just means that the *branch name* finds that particular commit as its tip commit.  So `H` is now the tip commit of `br2`.

We can go on to make one more commit on `br1`, if we want:

```
             I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- br2
```

If we now run `git checkout br2` or `git switch br2`, here's what Git has to do:

- Figure out which files exist in `br1`.  That is, figure out the set of files that go with commit `J`, the branch-tip commit.
- Figure out which files exist in `br2`: that is, the set of files that go with commit `H`.
- For the files that exist in both branch tip commits, some of them might be *different*.  If so, *replace the working tree copies of those files*.
- Some files might only exist in *one* of the two commits.  If so, remove or create the appropriate file in the working tree.
- Last, re-attach the special name `HEAD` to the chosen branch name.

We can draw this as:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

and we note that the *working tree files* have changed around, to match the tip commit of `br2`.  That is, our working tree is now that of commit `H`, not that of commit `J`.

At this point, we can make a new commit or two as usual.  They'll each get new unique hash IDs, which we will call `K` and `L`, and this will give us:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

As we switch back and forth between these two commits, Git will:

- remove from our working tree, any files that *are* in *this* commit but *aren't* in the *other* commit;
- add to our working tree, any files that *are* in the other commit but *aren't* in this commit;
- change, in our working tree, any files that are in both commits, but are *different* in the two commits.

For Git to do this, the files must actually be *in* one of those two commits.  For Git to *remove* files, the files must actually be *absent* from the *other* of these two commits.

#### Git's index or staging area

Now that you know the big secret of branches—that the word *branch* is ambiguous, that *branch names* find *tip commits;* that commits contain files (but not folders—Git just *makes* folders in your working tree when it has to do that to keep your OS happy); and that checking out or switching to some commit fills in your working tree *from* that commit—we're ready to take a closer look at the process of making a *new* commit.

Above, we just blithely assumed you know how to make new commits.  Of course, you *do* know how to do that.  But there is another big secret here.  Well, it's not really a *secret*, it's just that a lot of Git tutorials don't present it properly, and/or people miss it because there's so much stuff to learn all at once.

This secret, if it is really a secret, is that Git doesn't make new commits from the files in your *working tree*.  Instead, Git makes new commits—the snapshot part, at least—from the files that are in Git's *index*.

This name, "index", is not a very good name.  It's kind of meaningless.  So this thing has two more names.  All three names refer to the same thing.  The other main name is *staging area*, and this refers to how Git actually *uses* the index.  Git makes you "stage" a file for committing, by running `git add`.  You no doubt already know this—but the secret part is that `git add` doesn't *just* copy a file into Git's index.  **Most of the time, that file was already in Git's index before.**  What `git add` does is *replace* the file.

More precisely, `git add` tells Git: *Make the index copy of this file match my work-tree copy.*  Git will in fact *remove* the index copy of the file, if you've removed your work-tree copy, because that's how to make it match.  If the file is not in Git's index at all at this point, Git will *copy it into* its index.  Either way, once `git add` is done, the file in Git's index now matches the one (or the lack of one) in your working tree.  But the file may well already have been in Git's index.

The files in the index are in the special, read-only, Git-only, de-duplicated format.  The difference between the index copy and the committed copy is simply that the index copy *can be replaced* (by removing it wholesale, then inserting a different file: we never actually overwrite the index file since it's probably shared with some earlier commit).<sup>2</sup>  So, in effect, what's in Git's index is your *proposed next commit*.

To summarize this section, then, Git's index:

1. has three names: the *index*, the *staging area*, and the *cache* (the last one mostly shows up in command line flags these days, e.g., `git rm --cached`);
2. holds your *proposed next commit;*
3. holds a *third copy* of each file.

You already know there's a frozen committed copy of each file, which Git used to create your working tree copy, so that's *two* copies.  The index holds a *third* copy.  It starts out matching the committed copy, and keeps matching it until and unless you use `git add` or `git rm` or similar to *change or remove it*.

When you run `git commit`, Git makes the new snapshot from *whatever is in Git's index at this time*.  That's why you have to `git add` files over and over again.  You're not just telling Git that you changed the file, you're actually *storing* the updated file into Git's index, ready to go into the next commit.  (This makes `git commit` go incredibly fast, if you're used to older, pre-Git version control systems.  You could run their commit commands and go out for lunch sometimes.)

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what's in the index is:

- the file's name (including any embedded slashes);
- the file's mode (executable or non-executable);
- an internal *blob hash ID;* and
- a bunch of cache data and other internal but temporary data that don't go into the commits themselves.

The `git add` process compresses the file down to a pre-de-duplicated blob, or re-uses an existing blob if there is one with the right content.  It then updates the index entry.  There's more that happens when the index has been expanded for a conflicted merge, but this answer does not cover any of that.

---

#### Tracked, untracked, and ignored files, and the `git status` command

Once you properly understand Git's index / staging-area / cache, then—and *only* then—do Git's rules about untracked and ignored files make any sense.  The reason for this is simple and has to do with the definition of an untracked file, which is: **An untracked file is a file that exists in your working tree right now, that is not in Git's index right now.**  That's it: that is all there is to being untracked.

A *tracked file*, of course, is one that's in Git's index.  Generally these files probably should also be in your working tree.  Git doesn't actually *need* a copy to exist in your working tree, since the next commit will just use the index / staging-area copy, but it's weird to have the file in Git's index and not have it in your working tree.

An *ignored* file is one that not only is *untracked* but also is listed in your `.gitignore` file or similar.  Entries in ignore-files are used to *suppress complaints* about untracked files.

When you run `git status`, Git:

1. prints out the current branch name and other helpful stuff;
2. *compares* the *current commit*—the one found by `HEAD`, as we saw above—to the files in Git's index;
3. *compares* the index to your working tree.

Anything that Git finds, in step 2, that's *different*, Git calls *staged for commit*.  Since the index is the proposed next commit, whatever files are in it that are *the same* as the current commit aren't very interesting, and whatever files are in it that are *different* **are** interesting.  So these are the names that Git prints.

Anything that Git finds in step 3 that's different is also important.  These are files you *could* `git add`.  If you did, that would change the proposed next commit.  So Git prints these out as *unstaged files*.  (A tracked file that's missing from your working tree will show up as an unstaged delete, here.)

But—here's the oddity—instead of saying that there are unstaged files that could be added that aren't in Git's index at all, and calling those unstaged *added* files, Git calls them *untracked* files.  So if you have a bunch of files you don't *want* to commit, `git status` will whine about them, reminding you that it's time to add them to the index / staging-area.

This whining is annoying.  To make `git status` *shut up*, we list the file names in an ignore file.  Then `git status` sees them as untracked, but simply *does not complain*.  But note that if the files *are* in the index—*will* be in the proposed next commit—they *aren't untracked* and `git status` would not complain here, so **listing tracked files in `.gitignore` has no effect**.

In other words, **tracked files can't be ignored**.  But remember, a *tracked* file is one that's in Git's index *right now*.  How did it get there?  Can you remove it?

The answer to *how did it get there* is probably: *because it was in a commit*.  The other answer could be: *because I added it*.

The answer to *can you remove it* is *yes, of course*.  All you have to do is run `git rm`.  This removes both the index copy of the file, and your working tree copy of the file.  Of course, if you take it out of Git's index, it *won't* be in the next commit.  If it *is* in the *current* commit, and isn't in a new commit, the difference between those two commits includes the removal of that file.

There are two more features of `.gitignore` entries though:

- listing files here means that if they're currently untracked-and-ignored, an en-masse `git add`, such as `git add .`, *won't add them;* and
- listing a file here gives some Git operations permission to *destroy the working tree copy of the file* in some somewhat-unusual corner cases.

The latter is a good reason *not* to list a file in `.gitignore` if there's no reason to do so.

#### Conclusion

> This folder [named `raw`] is meant to be the `test`-branch's folder and I want it to be removed from the directory when I switch to `master` branch. How can I make [Git do that]?

Suppose you check out `test`, so that the tip commit of `test` is the current commit, *and* the files named `raw/*`—that your OS insists go into a folder named `raw`—are *contained in that commit* and are therefore currently tracked, i.e., in Git's index.  Suppose that the tip commit of `master` *lacks* those files.  Then `git checkout master` will *remove* those (tracked, thus not ignored) files.<sup>3</sup>

You *could* list `raw/` in a `.gitignore` but this would be entirely unhelpful: the files should already be absent when you have the tip commit of `master` checked out, and should come back when you have the tip commit of `test` checked out.  Those files are in various commits that are find-able from branch name `test` but not from branch name `master`; those files are *absent* in the commits find-able from branch name `master`.  (Any *shared* commits, on both branches, should lack the `raw/` files.)

Note that if you ever *merge* some of these commits, you may need to merge with `--no-commit` and fix up the merge result.  Merging—depending on the kind of merge, anyway—also makes commits "more findable", so the *direction* of the merge may become very important.  We'll leave this for other questions-and-answers, though.

---

<sup>3</sup>If Git removes all the files within some folder in your working tree, Git will generally remove the folder as well.  Note, though, that since Git doesn't actually *store* folders, it does not matter whether you have an empty folder in your working tree.  In fact, since Git builds commits from the files in Git's index, it only matters which files (complete with embedded slashes in their names) are in Git's index.

You don't normally look at what's *in* Git's index, though if you want to, try running `git ls-files --stage`.  Since this lists *every* file that will be in the next commit, its output is usually large and not useful.  The `git status` command *compares* the index to both the `HEAD` commit, to print the "staged for commit" list, and to your work-tree, to print the "not staged for commit" and "untracked" lists, and this is generally more useful than looking directly at the index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have committed it to the master branch or you have not committed it at all and it is local changes.

In case of the first scenario, checkout the master branch and delete the raw folder and commit. Now switch between the branches. You should see the raw folder in test branch but not in master branch.

In case of the second scenario, checkout test and commit your changes where you add the raw branch and .gitignore.

Another possible scenario is you added the raw folder to the master branch before you updated the .gitignore. Checkout master, delete the raw folder and commit. Switch back to your test branch and add the raw folder, update the .gitignore, and commit.

Comment: I commited all changes and the `test` branch is clean. When I switch to `master`, the `git status` tells me about `untracked raw folder`.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository